# Can I use USB A to HDMI for monitor output?

Tags: usb, hdmi, adapter

The HDMI socket on my HP Envy 15 Notebook recently packed up. It would be unfeasible for me to replace the socket.

Would it be possible for me to use a USB A to HDMI cable for monitor output? This model of laptop has functioning 3 USB A, ethernet and audio socket, so no other outlet for media.

Using my external screen is better for my neck, as I don't have the space to prop my laptop up further. I have a desktop, but is 10 years old and runs slow so I don't use it.

Comment: It depends. Do you do any demanding graphics operations like gaming on your laptop?

Comment: A little. I mostly want to know if USB to HDMI display is even possible, and would it depend on the type of USB sockets my laptop has?

Comment: Sure it’s possible, but it’ll be a USB graphics solution (DisplayLink). The laptop’s GPU will not be used to output the image.

Answer (score 0):

There exist adapters for converting USB-A to HDMI, but the examples I have found
all require USB-3, probably because of power and speed requirements:
[example1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01NCLHNVW)
($19.59 + shipping)
and
[example2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B072FHTZ8V)
($89.99 + shipping).

These adapters will include a built-in embedded display adapter that will be nowhere
as good as the graphic adapter of your computer, but they will let you use
the computer without repairs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are USB devices (aka video adapters) that provide MULTIPLE monitor outputs even on USB2.0 ports, for [example this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01AL6IBF8).

[image]

The device is based on DisplayLink DL-165 chip.

From description,

> WAVLINK USB 2.0 adapters supports HDMI and DVI / VGA ( DVI to VGA
>   adapters are supplied for added flexibility ) , provides the ultimate
>   multi-monitor productivity and hot desk expansion. It allows you to
>   easily connect extra monitors ( TV ) to your Laptop PC Ultrabook
>   Tablet, a brand new visual feast for you.(one display adapter can
>   extend one monitor)

There are several makers of similar devices. However, the display is done via "virtual video driver", fully in host software, so the external display is only good for general office-kind tasks.